# "Index was outside the bounds of the array" error while publishing a .NET Web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-webpages

I have a simple .NET Web application that works fine when I run it on my local machine. However, when I try to publish the application to a local folder, I see the error that says "Index was outside the bounds of the array." This error, I'm afraid, is very vague and I am not able to figure out what the issue is.

[image]

I am creating this project on Visual Studio community 2019.

Can someone please help me figure out what the issue is :)

Comment: I am experiencing this error in Jan 2021. Buy trying to add a network path as a deployment location. Using VS Community 2019. I have done this successfully on VS 2017.

Comment: This error has plagued my VS installation for a few years. I have tried reinstallations and different versions without change. It appears to be a system issue that I can't narrow down and is vague enough that searching for help is difficult.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know the issue or solution for this, but here is a workaround I used.
Essentially, you will need to create the publish folder and file profiles manually.

I did this for a .NET Core 3.1 Blazor project

Step 1 - In your project, go to the *Properties* folder where you should find your launchSettings.json

Step 2 - Inside, create a folder and name it *"PublishProfiles"*

Step 3 - Inside of the *PublishProfiles* folder, create a file and name it *"FolderProfile.pubxml"*

Step 4 - Inside of this file, paste this code and add the location path to the folder you which to publish:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
    -->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
        <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
        <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
        <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
        <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
        <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
        <PublishUrl>Your location path where you want to publish your application</PublishUrl>
        <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
        <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
        <ProjectGuid>08d93ba4-c83c-47e9-a83e-73f12d97626a</ProjectGuid>
        <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Step 5 - Create another file and name it *"FolderProfile.pubxml.user"* and paste this code inside. Again, insert the path to your desired folder:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
    -->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <_PublishTargetUrl>Your location path where you want to publish your application</_PublishTargetUrl>
        <History>True|2021-07-02T16:47:41.7255934Z;True|2021-07-02T12:44:24.1064885-04:00;True|2021-05-21T09:22:02.2383330-04:00;True|2021-05-20T17:42:40.0758569-04:00;True|2021-05-20T09:45:45.4390896-04:00;True|2021-05-20T09:02:32.8340404-04:00;</History>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Step 6 - After this, you should be able to right click your project in Visual Studio, click the option Publish... and the screen with the Publish button should be visible.

Comment: this solution worked for me. identical issue visual studio 2019 with .netcore 5 project.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a workaround but works.
Use **Release** instead of **Debug** in Solution Configuration options at the top of Visual Studio and copy the generated file from "bin\Release" folder to your destination "Publish" folder.